# How to save the text box values into an array?

Tags: vb6

I need to enter values in text box and when ever i press enter i have to save the text box values into an array.How can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: Is this a multi-line edit box, and you want to add one value per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a separate counter variable to redefine the size of the array, like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myArr() As String  '~~~ dynamic array
Dim lngCnt As Long     '~~~ a counter variable that keep track of the index

' inital stage..
Private Sub Form_Load()
    lngCnt = 0
End Sub

' on KeyPress
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then   '~~~ if Enter Key is pressed..
        ReDim Preserve myArr(lngCnt)    '~~~ reclare the array with the new size, while preserving any elements it may contain
        myArr(lngCnt) = Text1.Text      '~~~ store the line
        Text1.Text = ""     '~~~ empty the textbox, so that you could type the next line

        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1 '~~~ increment the counter, which we would use as size during the next keypress
    End If
End Sub

' to display the elements
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)  '~~~ loop through the elements(from Lowerbound to Upperbound)..
        Debug.Print myArr(i)                '~~~ ..and display the item.
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: ThanK You...Akhilesh B Chandran

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a new entry to be added each time they press the button, then use something like:

```
Redim Preserve YourArray(LBound(YourArray) To UBound(YourArray) + 1)
YourArray(UBound(YourArray)) = TextBox.Text
```

Note that this can get very slow and inefficient when the array contains large numbers of items as it's reallocating memory each time.
A better method would involve expanding the size of the array in chunks, while keeping track of the last valid entry.

Answer (score 0):

Just give same name to all the text Boxes

Comment: I need to use only one text box

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use [split](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter) to break the string up (you will need to tell the user what char to use to split on).

Long answer  don't change the user interface to a repeater and have them use an input per value start here http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/basil/archive/2008/08/20/javascript-repeater-control-datarepeater-using-jquery-presenter-1-0-8-uicontrols-library.aspx

Else you will be debugging for ever.

Comment: This question has been tagged VB6 - your answer seems to be for ASP.NET.